# Node error on route node_modules/pangyp/bin/node-gyp

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to run a project but this error is coming up everytime I try to do whatever I do.

I already did

`rm -rf node_modules`

`npm install` `npm install -g`

`npm update` `npm update -g`

`npm install node-sass` `npm rebuild node-sass`

and also I did try with `sudo` command

and etc and still getting this output

```
CRSJOPGP0223:promo-payment-reminder-text berretan$ sudo npm rebuild node-sass

> node-sass@2.1.1 install /Users/berretan/Documents/Projects/promo-payment-reminder-text/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js


> node-sass@2.1.1 postinstall /Users/berretan/Documents/Projects/promo-payment-reminder-text/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

module.js:328
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/berretan/Documents/Projects/promo-payment-reminder-text/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/pangyp/bin/node-gyp'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
Build failed
node-sass@2.1.1
```

node version: 4.2.6

Comment: `npm install --verbose` might show you a bit more info

Comment: also the latest version of node-sass is 3.4.2